# create a new variable in r based on cycling timestamps (s) to identify replicates

Tags: r

I have the following dummy data:

```
x<-c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2)
y<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
z<-c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
a<-data.frame(x,y,z)
```

however I would like to add a variable to identify the replicates based on the cycle of x

```
f<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
b<-data.frame(a,f)
head(b)
```

[image]

I need to use code to this as I have 48 individuals with 1000s of observations each potentially a different length of x (seconds). Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: With new cycle you mean that `x` starts with 0 again?

Comment: yes, 48 times in the real data set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` and `diff` to count the occurences when x returns to 0, or even just moves backwards

```r
a$f <- c(0, cumsum(diff(a$x) < 0)) + 1
a
#>   x y z f
#> 1 0 1 2 1
#> 2 1 1 2 1
#> 3 2 1 2 1
#> 4 3 1 2 1
#> 5 0 1 2 2
#> 6 1 1 2 2
#> 7 2 1 2 2
```

Comment: just a bit more compact `a$f <- diffinv(diff(a$x) < 0, xi = 1)`

Answer (score 2):

If a cycle is started by `x == 0`, then all you need to do is calculate your column `f` as follows:

```
f <- cumsum(a$x == 0)
```

If, more generally, you need to check whether a value in the `x` column is not strictly larger than its predecessor (and thus denotes a new cycle), try this:

```
f <- cumsum(a$x <= c(Inf, a$x[-nrow(a)]))
```

The above compares every observation in `a$x` against a shifted version of the vector - with an `Inf` value prepended to make sure the first observation counts as a new cycle and the last observation removed, so that that vector has same length.
*// please see Allan Cameron's answer below for a more elegant approach to this, using `diff`*